# Combining lists of unequal length to form a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you join a list with another list of unequal length to result to a dictionary

```
list_header=['a','b']
list_value=[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,7,8]
```

Result dictionary:

`{"iteration1":{'a':1,'b':2},"iteration2":{'a':3,'b':4}, "iteration3":{'a':5,'b':6}, "iteration4":{'a':7,'b':8} }`

Comment: Your result doesn't make sense; keys have to be unique so the output would just be `{'a': 7, 'b': 8}`, the previous values get overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (based on changed question)

You can generate the result you want with a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
out = { "iteration" + str(i+1) : { list_header[j] : list_value[i*len(list_header)+j] for j in range(len(list_header)) } for i in range(len(list_value) // len(list_header)) }
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'iteration3': {'b': 6, 'a': 5}, 'iteration2': {'b': 4, 'a': 3}, 'iteration4': {'b': 8, 'a': 7}, 'iteration1': {'b': 2, 'a': 1}}
```

**Original Answer**

You can't create a dictionary like that; dictionary keys must be unique. You could create a list of tuples though:

```
list_header=['a','b']
list_value=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

out = [(h, v) for h, v in zip(list_header * (len(list_value) // len(list_header) + 1), list_value)]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('a', 5), ('b', 6), ('a', 7), ('b', 8)]
```